# react file is not render when run on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend

i download bootstrap template for project and when i run the script on browser nothing shows up.
where is the problem in this code i expect to show-up output on my local-host.

## home.jsx i remove most code because stack overflow gives me err i hope you can understand code.

```
import React from "react";
import ChartistGraph from "react-chartist";
// react-bootstrap components
import {
//   Badge,
  Button,
  Card,
//   Navbar,
//   Nav,
  Table,
  Container,
  Row,
  Col,
  Form,
  OverlayTrigger,
  Tooltip,
} from "react-bootstrap";

function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col lg="3" sm="6">
            <Card className="card-stats">
              <Card.Body>
                <Row>
                  <Col xs="5">
                    <div className="icon-big text-center icon-warning">
                      <i className="nc-icon nc-chart text-warning"></i>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="7">
                    <div className="numbers">
                      <p className="card-category">Number</p>
                      <Card.Title as="h4">150GB</Card.Title>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer>
                <hr></hr>
                <div className="stats">
                  <i className="fas fa-redo mr-1"></i>
                  Update Now
                </div>
              </Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          </Col>
          <Col lg="3" sm="6">
            <Card className="card-stats">
              <Card.Body>
                <Row>
                  <Col xs="5">
                    <div className="icon-big text-center icon-warning">
                      <i className="nc-icon nc-light-3 text-success"></i>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="7">
                    <div className="numbers">
                      <p className="card-category">Revenue</p>
                      <Card.Title as="h4">$ 1,345</Card.Title>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer>
                <hr></hr>
                <div className="stats">
                  <i className="far fa-calendar-alt mr-1"></i>
                  Last day
                </div>
              </Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          </Col>
          <Col lg="3" sm="6">
            <Card className="card-stats">
              <Card.Body>
                <Row>
                  <Col xs="5">
                    <div className="icon-big text-center icon-warning">
                      <i className="nc-icon nc-vector text-danger"></i>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="7">
                    <div className="numbers">
                      <p className="card-category">Errors</p>
                      <Card.Title as="h4">23</Card.Title>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer>
                <hr></hr>
                <div className="stats">
                  <i className="far fa-clock-o mr-1"></i>
                  In the last hour
                </div>
              </Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          </Col>
          <Col lg="3" sm="6">
            <Card className="card-stats">
              <Card.Body>
                <Row>
                  <Col xs="5">
                    <div className="icon-big text-center icon-warning">
                      <i className="nc-icon nc-favourite-28 text-primary"></i>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                  <Col xs="7">
                    <div className="numbers">
                      <p className="card-category">Followers</p>
                      <Card.Title as="h4">+45K</Card.Title>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Card.Body>
              <Card.Footer>
                <hr></hr>
                <div className="stats">
                  <i className="fas fa-redo mr-1"></i>
                  Update now
                </div>
              </Card.Footer>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col md="8">
            <Card>
              <Card.Header>
                <Card.Title as="h4">Users Behavior</Card.Title>
                <p className="card-category">24 Hours performance</p>
              </Card.Header>
             
export default Dashboard;
```

## app.js

```
import { Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./home/home";
import Signup from "./Signup/Signup";
import Login from "./Login/Login";

function App() {
    // const user = localStorage.getItem("access_token");

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/signup" exact element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/login" exact element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/Home" exact element={<Home/>} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/Home"/>} />
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default App;
```

## this is unexpected output

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBr2j.png)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no there is no err it compile successfully

Comment: Which version of React Router is this?

Comment: And is your App component wrapped in `<BrowserRouter>`?

Comment: <BrowserRouter> has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

In app.js you have routed  to Home page and called the  method but your method name is Dashboard.

Comment: sorry i cant understand can you elaborate

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if Dashboard is the main component, path should be like this `path="/"`

```
import {Dashboard} from './Dashboard'

return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/signup" exact element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/login" exact element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
    );
```

Comment: ``` import { Route, Routes, Navigate, } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./home/home";
import Signup from "./Signup/Signup";
import Login from "./Login/Login";

function Dashboard() {
 // const user = localStorage.getItem("access_token");


return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/signup" exact element={<Signup />} />
            <Route path="/login" exact element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/home" exact element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default Dashboard; ``` i change this code still it not work

Comment: main component is function Dashboard(){.....}